# Selenium C# Switching Focus between two Web Browsers

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have created two IWebDriver objects. One for a FireFox browser and the other for a Chrome Browser. I am struggling to switch focus between the two browsers though. I have tried using the following:-

```
_webDriver2 = new ChromeDriver();
string chromeHandle = _webDriver2.CurrentWindowHandle; 

_webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
string fireFoxHandle = _webDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;

_webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(fireFoxHandle); 
_webDriver2.SwitchTo().Window(chromeHandle);
```

But this doesnt seem to bring the web browsers into focus. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

No current driver implementations do any work to bring the OS-level window of the browser to the foreground. In certain operating systems (I'm looking at you, Windows), it's not possible to reliably bring any given application window to the foreground, since that's an arms race that can never be won. The `switchTo().window()` method (in whatever language binding) only switches between multiple windows of a given browser within the same browser session. That is, started by the same `WebDriver` instance. Furthermore, all it does is direct to which window the driver commands are sent, not which one is in the "foreground" of the OS. If you really think you require such functionality, you can try using OS-specific mechanisms like API calls using the appropriate native language interfaces for your language (JNI for Java, P/Invoke for .NET, etc.), but those mechanisms will likely not be cross-platform.